# How can I access iCloud synced data from my web application?

Tags: ios, web-applications, icloud

Suppose I have built an iOS App, and maybe a Mac App, and they all use iCloud to store data and to sync it across devices.

Now, suppose I want to build a web based application where users can log in to a web site and access the same data.

How can I do this? More specifically, which technology stack will allow me to do this?

I expect that I would like to integrate with iCloud from the server. Is there an API that can be used? Are there wrappers to invoke from Java, .NET (C#), Ruby (Rails) or Node.js? I imagine that each user will need to authorise my application to access *their* iCloud account. Does iCloud support per-application and user authorisation?